# Jquery form validation not showing error message

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate my form using jquery but I cannot get it work. When I click on submit it doesn't show any error message.

Could you please tell me where is the problem?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js"></script>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() { 
// validate signup form on keyup and submit 
var validator = $("#signupform").validate({ 
    rules: { 
        fname: "required", 
        lname: "required", 
        username: { 
            required: true, 
            minlength: 2, 
            remote: "<? echo base_url();?>mycontroller/function" }
       }, 
    messages: { 
        fname: "Enter your firstname", 
        lname: "Enter your lastname", 
        username: { 
            required: "Enter a username", 
            minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters"), 
            remote: jQuery.format("{0} is already in use") 
        }, 

    }, 



}); 

</script>
```

My FOrm

```
 <!--I am trying to show all the error message here --> 

<form id="signupform" autocomplete="off" method="get" action="">

 FName:
 <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" value="" />
 Lname:
 <input id="lname" name="lname" type="text" value="" />
 username:
 <input id="username" name="username" type="text" value="" />   <br>      

 <input id="signupsubmit" name="signup" type="submit" value="Signup" />          
 </form>
```

Comment: its working here http://jsfiddle.net/85DM4/9/

Comment: @john. I had to add `});` in the bottom of the code to make it work. But I have a question to ask if you don't mind, could you please tell me how to show all the error messages separated by comma inside `<span class="something"></span>` Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i mentioned in the comments it working in the fiddle

make sure the scripts are loaded you can try using the cdn hosted version of jquery and validate.js

**jquery cdn**

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js

**validate.js cdn**

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery.Validate/1.6/jQuery.Validate.js

if it works with this it means that the scripts are not loaded and check your links

EDIT

```
$(":submit").click(function(e){

    if(!$(this).closest("form").valid()){
        e.preventDefault();
        var errText="";
        $(".error").each(function(i,j){
         errText+=$(j).text()+"<br/>";           
        });
        $("#errDiv").html(errText).css({color:'Red'});  

        }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/85DM4/17/

its not comma separated but i'm sure you will get the idea

Comment: is this the fiddle link? http://jsfiddle.net/85DM4/17/ . I just tried it but found it still showing the error message beside the fields

Comment: only in the last field the first name and the last name field errors are removed, why on the last field it doing such behavior it beyond my comprehension at the moment